macOS dyld no such file even though file exists
I am trying to run an executable which links a dynamic library in the /Applications folder but dyld keeps complaining that it can't find the library:
dyld[8425]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libmylibrary.dylib
  Referenced from: <...> ...
  Reason: tried: '/Applications/.../libmylibrary.dylib' (no such file), ...

Even though the first path it says it tried, /Applications/.../libmylibrary.dylib is the correct path of the library and definitely exists on my system. I thought it might be a permission issue so I chmod-ed that whole directory to 777 and that didn't fix it.

What is rpath set to in the executable?  Use otool -l <yourexe> | more and look for LC_RPATH sections.
